# Changes in Handling of Real Zeros

Tags: evaluation

I recently upgraded from Mathematica 5 to Mathematica 8 and I have a number of notebooks that no longer work correctly.  The problems relate to the use of units.  I don't need complicated unit conversions so I typically just tag values with symbols for the units.  Under Mathematica 5, I could write the following (I understand that this example isn't physically meaningful):

```
3. in + 4. in - 7. in + 5. lb
```

And Mathematica would return

```
5. lb
```

Now, under Mathematica 8, I get

```
0. + 5. lb
```

This breaks a large number of notebooks.  Can someone explain what is happening, and what if anything I can do to get the old behavior back?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only precise zero coefficients are eliminated.  Use [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Chop.html):

```
3. in + 4. in - 7. in + 5. lb // Chop
```

> ```
> 5. lb
> ```

---

Leonid admonished me for posting a method overloading `Times`.  I didn't honestly expect anyone to use that and I think I made that pretty clear in the original post.

Nevertheless, here is a safer method that only affects uses of specified units:

```
units = {in, lb};

(# /: 0. # := 0 #) & /@ units;

3. in + 4. in - 7. in + 5. lb
```

> ```
> 5. lb
> ```

Comment: You have just committed a deadly sin (and you know about it): *nothing* can excuse overloading `Times` (or similar commands) globally. Why don't you use a local dynamic environment?  I am afraid that your answer in its present form will lead to many lost souls.

Comment: I would actually propose this: `$Post = (# /. HoldPattern[Times[0., x : __ : 1]] :> Times[0, x]) &`.

Comment: @Leonid naughty, aren't I? :->  The problem with `Post` is that it only affects the output.  If I remove the overloading method will you vote for `Chop`?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Though I completely agree that it is bad practice to overload arithmetic functions like `Times` the fan boy in me loves the fact that we can. Mathematica is like putty in the hands, leaving us free to experiment with it in ways that just aren't possible in most places.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I can't try anything until Monday, but I really appreciate the quick response!

Comment: @Andy Yes, I agree :). I've done enough of this myself :). Also agree about the feel of Mathematica. Someone (don't remember who) told about LISP, that "(LISP) is not a language, it is a building material".

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You can *probably* overload `Times` locally with a combination of ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` and Gayley-Villegas trick, and such that the user-defined rule is applied *after* the built-in (post-processing), in which case I would assume that it will be reasonably safe. Not sure about `Chop` - I can imagine cases where it is not desirable.